# Ubuntu 19.04 Unity Workspaces Missing

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

Just upgraded from 18 to 19 and my Unity / Compiz workspaces are only 4 instead of the configured 5 horizontal by 2 vertical (10 total)

May be related: windows don't show previews when dragging on this nvidia driver

Answer (score 0):

Well, restarting fixed it. I guess loging out/in after installing a nvidia driver is not enough to truly unload/reload all the components.